# local variable declaration with 'is' keyword VS 'as' keyword performance difference

Tags: c#, performance, keyword

```
object obj = "Hello";

// is keyword
if (obj is string str1)
{
   Console.WriteLine(str1);
}

// as keyword
string str2 = obj as string;
if (str2 != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine(str2);
}
```

In the code above, the local variable is declared with the 'is' keyword, but is there any difference in performance with the 'as' keyword?

I wonder if there is a performance difference related to casting and null checking. (Aside from local scope differences of str1 and str2 variables)

Comment: Pretty sure they compile to the same IL. You can try compiling it on sharplab.io.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's a nice utility. When comparing IL, it came out exactly the same.

Comment: Side note: even though it doesn't matter here, you should prefer `is object` to `!= null` - the difference is that `!= null` can invoke custom equality/conversion operators, which *can* be more overhead than a simple null test; the `is object` syntax never invokes operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two code samples are absolutely 100% identical; we can test this by looking at the IL, which can be done in many ways, but the most convenient for ad-hoc things is https://sharplab.io/

Consider:

```cs
using System;
public class C {
    object obj = "Hello";
    public void ViaIsWithCapture()
    {
        // is keyword
        if (obj is string str1)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(str1);
        }
    }
    public void ViaAsThenNullTest()
    {
        // as keyword
        string str2 = obj as string;
        if (str2 != null)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(str2);
        }
    }
}
```

We can run this through sharplab.io [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs7omACsYwGbnzoBeOgCIAEjFy4IEgNwcutBijoA1bAEMAkgGcA6tgwALJjoAOGAK6wAFAEoVndpS6e6Aem91sBnQA1jAAngDu0AAmrl7YAGZ0Djy8/oGEpAAMdAYYUKQuHl5uscUMpACcDrn5TspFxQC+sc0NDPSEGto6AIIGACpmMAB2AHK2cv0wuc6x7mU+fjqBIRHRpapZOXnEYsKpy+WZ9QsJSTW7AITiwxO4hQvzC5wZVRd1G5ytnq2NQA===), and if you look on the right, the IL for both versions works out *identical*:

```
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void ViaIsWithCapture () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 22 (0x16)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] string str1
        )

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld object C::obj
        IL_0006: isinst [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String
        IL_000b: stloc.0
        IL_000c: ldloc.0
        IL_000d: brfalse.s IL_0015

        IL_000f: ldloc.0
        IL_0010: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)

        IL_0015: ret
    } // end of method C::ViaIsWithCapture
```

vs

```
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance void ViaAsThenNullTest () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2074
        // Code size 22 (0x16)
        .maxstack 1
        .locals init (
            [0] string str2
        )

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld object C::obj
        IL_0006: isinst [System.Private.CoreLib]System.String
        IL_000b: stloc.0
        IL_000c: ldloc.0
        IL_000d: brfalse.s IL_0015

        IL_000f: ldloc.0
        IL_0010: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(string)

        IL_0015: ret
    } // end of method C::ViaAsThenNullTest
```

Answer (score -2):

This code is better:

```
string str2 = obj as string;
if (str2 != null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(str2);
  }
```

CLR is checking this once while the first one is doing two times, first with IS operator and later in typecasting, which is obviously an overhead.

Comment: Funnily enough, things that are "obvious" are often wrong; in this case, the two versions are *absolutely 100% identical* - compare the IL here: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs7omACsYwGbnzoBeOgCIAEjFy4IEgNwcutBijoA1bAEMAkgGcA6tgwALJjoAOGAK6wAFAEoVndpS6e6Aem91sBnQA1jAAngDu0AAmrl7YAGZ0Djy8/oGEpAAMdAYYUKQuHl5uscUMpACcDrn5TspFxQC+sc0NDPSEGto6AIIGACpmMAB2AHK2cv0wuc6x7mU+fjqBIRHRpapZOXnEYsKpy+WZ9QsJSTW7AITiwxO4hQvzC5wZVRd1G5ytnq2NQA===